# Why does data table print inside an if block?

Tags: r, data.table, verbosity

Why does this happen?

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)  # For revalue

set.seed(123098)
my_table <- data.table(x=1:10, str=sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=T))
my_table[, y := 3*x + runif(nrow(my_table))]  # Runs silently

mapping <- c("a"="andrew", "b"="barbarian", "c"="constant", "d"="deft")
my_table[, new_str := revalue(str, replace=mapping)]  # Runs silently

some_condition <- TRUE
if(some_condition) {
    my_table[, y := 3*x + runif(nrow(my_table))]  # Runs silently
    my_table[, new_str := revalue(str, replace=mapping)]  # Why does this print?
}
```

Notice the second call to `new_str := revalue(str, replace=mapping)` -- on my machine it causes the data table to print.  In this little example that doesn't matter much, but I have an R script operating on a large data table, and I'd rather not have unneeded printouts in the logs.  Why does this happen and how can I stop it?

Edit:  in case this is helpful:

```
$ R --version
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

And my R session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.1       data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45  Rcpp_0.11.3   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2
```

Comment: What is "runs silently"? With your example, I always have something printed out.

Comment: I don't get any printout.  @Pascal, you get printouts even for the lines that are outside of the if block?

Comment: To be clear:  if I run the code above, the only printout I get is the data table, printed once, and that's coming from the new_str := revalue call inside the if block.

Comment: Yes, it prints out the result (data.table 1.9.5).

Comment: Pretty strange. Can't see why it happens. I have the table printed when the assignation is made in an `if` statement: `data(iris);setDT(iris);if (TRUE) iris[,y:=1]` prints the table. With `invisible(iris[,y:=1])` you avoid the output.

Comment: I don't get anything printed out using the devel version (v 1.9.5). Try installing it from GH and then try again.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I use v 1.9.5 and it is printed out.

Comment: @Pascal then reinstall it (don't forget to close all R sessions before). Your version is probably older as it is getting updated almost daily

Comment: @DavidArenburg Let's try. OK. After update, anything is printed out.

Comment: @nicola thank you for suggesting `invisible`, that's a nice way to remove the printout without having to reinstall anything.

Comment: For me (on 1.9.4) it prints the last line of the if block.  For example if I remove the line that sets `new_str` then it'll print the result of the previous line.  If I add a "do nothing" line at the end like `my_table=my_table` then nothing is printed.  This doesn't really *answer* the question as to why it does this but does expand on it.

Comment: Using Rstudio results in printing the last line.  Running `source(file)` from R does not print the last line.  Running Rscript(file) also prints the last line.